# filter each array item with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that converts any `#` in a string to a hash tag array

```
myArr= myStr.match(/#\S+/g);
```

I also have a this to filter out from a string anything other than alpah numeric minus underscore.

```
myStr= myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g, "");
```

But now i want to combine these 2 to make sure that each of the items in that array contain only alpha numeric values including underscore and the `#` in the begining.

Can anyone help out please,  thank you.

Comment: You can't since it is two different operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated?

```
myArr = myStr.match(/#[a-z0-9_]+/gi);
```

EDIT: I misunderstood your intention. Here's a slightly less simple, but altogether more efficient, solution:

```
myArr = myStr.replace(/#\S+/g,function(m) {
    return "#"+m.replace(/[^a-z0-9_]+/gi,"");
}).match(/#\S+/g);
```

Comment: @NoahR Uh, no. It's intentional.

Comment: thank you,  i took off the `i`.  when i enter `#hello_wor-ld` expecting `#hello_world`,  i get `#h`

Comment: That's because I missed the `+`, sorry!

Comment: so i put the `g` back in and `#hello_wor-ld` produces `["#hello_wor"]`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol I was just testing you ;)

Comment: with the `i` out i get the same output

Comment: @tq That's because you didn't specify `-` as a valid character. Just throw it in at the end (`a-z0-9_-`) and it should work. The `i` is there because then you don't need to specify `a-zA-Z`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol oh,  no i would like to omit that.  the regex stops after.  I was hoping to treat those characters as empty string and concat the ends together like the second regex i had `myStr= myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g, "");`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol WOW that was awesome!